# rstatix package installation

Tags: r, windows, rstatix

I´m having problems with the "rstatix" package installation. When the installation finishes and I try to run the library, I get this message:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rstatix’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.2.0 is being loaded, but >= 0.3.2 is required
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘rstatix’ was built under R version 3.6.3
```

Have any of you dealt with this problem before? How did you solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the "vctrs" package should be >= 0.3.2. Try to update the "vctrs" package to the latest one.

```
# below is the command to update the package  
install.packages("vctrs")

# if you want to update all packages   
update.packages()
```

After this try to import your package.